# Add chef groups instead of list of users to chef vauts

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How can I add groups for access to chef vaults instead of having to specify a list of user accounts?

I'd like to do this:

```
knife vault create vault item1 <json> --admins serverAdminsGroup --search --mode client
```

But I get: `ChefVault::Exceptions::AdminNotFound: FATAL: Could not find fart in users or clients!`

According to [the docs](https://github.com/chef/chef-vault) this isn't possible with admin switch:

> -A ADMINS --admins      ADMINS    Chef clients or users to be vault admins, can be comma list

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported, as it says you can only use clients and users. Groups exist only within the ACL system, they are not API-level entities for most purposes.